# OpenNLP classifier output

Tags: java, text, machine-learning, opennlp, categorization

At the moment I'm using the following code to train a classifier model :

```
    final String iterations = "1000";
    final String cutoff = "0";
    InputStreamFactory dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(new File("src/main/resources/trainingSets/classifierA.txt"));
    ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
    ObjectStream<DocumentSample> sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);

    TrainingParameters params = new TrainingParameters();
    params.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, iterations);
    params.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, cutoff);
    params.put(AbstractTrainer.ALGORITHM_PARAM, NaiveBayesTrainer.NAIVE_BAYES_VALUE);

    DoccatModel model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("NL", sampleStream, params, new DoccatFactory());

    OutputStream modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/models/model.bin"));
    model.serialize(modelOut);

    return model;
```

This goes well and after every run I get the following output :

```
    Indexing events with TwoPass using cutoff of 0

    Computing event counts...  done. 1474 events
    Indexing...  done.
Collecting events... Done indexing in 0,03 s.
Incorporating indexed data for training...  
done.
    Number of Event Tokens: 1474
        Number of Outcomes: 2
      Number of Predicates: 4149
Computing model parameters...
Stats: (998/1474) 0.6770691994572592
...done.
```

Could someone explain what this output means? And if it tells something about the accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/ml/naivebayes/NaiveBayesTrainer.java#L109), we can tell this output is done by [NaiveBayesTrainer::trainModel](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/ml/naivebayes/NaiveBayesTrainer.html#trainModel-opennlp.tools.ml.model.DataIndexer-) method:

```
public AbstractModel trainModel(DataIndexer di) {
    // ...
    display("done.\n");
    display("\tNumber of Event Tokens: " + numUniqueEvents + "\n");
    display("\t    Number of Outcomes: " + numOutcomes + "\n");
    display("\t  Number of Predicates: " + numPreds + "\n");
    display("Computing model parameters...\n");
    MutableContext[] finalParameters = findParameters();
    display("...done.\n");
    // ...
}
```

If you take a look at `findParameters()` code, you'll notice that it calls the `trainingStats()` method, which contains the code snippet that calculates the accuracy:

```
private double trainingStats(EvalParameters evalParams) {
    // ...
    double trainingAccuracy = (double) numCorrect / numEvents;
    display("Stats: (" + numCorrect + "/" + numEvents + ") " + trainingAccuracy + "\n");
    return trainingAccuracy;
}
```

**TL;DR the `Stats: (998/1474) 0.6770691994572592` part of the output is the accuracy you're looking for.**

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, I have 1 question left. Where is `numCorrect` based on? In this trainingsset are `998` numbers `2` and the rest are under number `4`. Why are the numbers `2` the `numCorrect` ones?

Comment: @Patrick `numCorrect` is also calculated in `trainingStats()`. Take a look at [the source in GitHub](https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/ml/naivebayes/NaiveBayesTrainer.java#L179).

Comment: @Patrick If you find this answer useful, do not forget to "accept" it by clicking the Nike logo just below the up/down arrows. :-)

Comment: Yes ofcourse, Was just testing out if I understand it now.

Comment: One more little thing. I get also as output : `1 outcome patterns
1 : 0.009484261328269445` does this mean 94% accuracy or something else? Thanks.

Comment: The `outcome parts` output is printed by [`NaiveBayesModelWriter`](https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/ml/naivebayes/NaiveBayesModelWriter.java#L129), but the decimal part must come from somewhere else.

Comment: The decimal part is comming from the  `aProbs` list is this also telling me something about the accuracy? its comming from the following lines of code   `String[] docWords = sentences[i].toLowerCase().split(" "); double[] aProbs = doccat.categorize(docWords);`

Comment: [`DocumentCategorizerME::categorize`](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/doccat/DocumentCategorizerME.html#categorize-java.lang.String:A-) returns the probabilities of `docWords` belonging to each category.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Greetings.